# OmniAuth Options Hash

Tags: omniauth, cas

I am writing my own CAS strategy and I would like the user to pass my strategy their distinguished name (from their cert).  From my understanding, a user of my strategy can pass options like this

```
use OmniAuth::Strategies::CAS::MyStrategy :setup => true
```

I'm assuming in the options tag within my strategy's initialize method, I will have a key setup => value of true.  This gets passed along to the CAS class (via the super method) and so forth.  Could the user pass an option like this :dn => retrieve_dn_method to do what I've stated above?  If so, what would the parent classes do with an option they're not expecting?

Or is there another way of passing options into my strategy that I need to authenticate?

Comment: I've researched the OmniAuth documentation and I haven't found anything that could help.  The documentation is sparse, so any links or two cents are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the :setup option will be present in the options hash which is passed into your strategy's initialize method.  Setting :setup to true only allows the user of the strategy to create a setup method in their code to accomplish a task before authenticating.  But based off of this:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers users of your strategy should be able to set the person's distinguished name in this way:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def setup
    request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:dn] = user_dn
    render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
  end
end
```